# On reading "The Sacred"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives

**Sacred** is an adjective (Random House Dictionary, 1967). 
It would seem that one cannot let te word simply dangle: it must refer to something (as in: the sacred land; the sacred text.)
Yet the (translated) title of Rudolph Otto's famous book is:

> The Idea of the Holy.

True, it obviously is a Germanism. The (relevant part of the) original title is:

> Das Heilige.

Has that form now become commonplace enough so that I may speak of
"The Sacred" as in the title I am contemplating, for a paper discussing interpretation of sacred texts:

> **"On Reading the Sacred"?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of a fused Modifier-Head construction, as described in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002). Here the adjective *sacred* is functioning as the Head of the noun phrase. But it is also understood as a Modifier of some unexpressed noun. Here are some more examples:

- the good, the bad and the ugly
- the French, the English, the Dutch
- You take the red, and I'll take the blue
- the blind, the poor
- the best was yet to come

We can also find determiners functioning as fused Modifier-Heads

- I'll take the two by the door.

The Original Poster's fused Modifier-Head noun phrase is commonly seen in in partnership with another in the [binomial](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198465/pros-and-cons-black-and-white-ups-and-downs-always-in-a-fixed-sequence/198474#198474):

- the sacred and the profane.

All of these, of course, are completely grammatical. We wouldn't call *sacred* a proper noun here, though. It's occurring with a determiner. But most importantly, it isn't a noun!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an adjective can be used as a noun, and a proper noun if appropriate.

"On Reading the Sacred" would be understood to mean "On Reading the Sarcred (Writings)" (or Things) by most readers.

See [this article](https://www.englishgrammar.org/adjectives-nouns-2/) and [this article](https://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/15695-can-an-adjective-become-a-noun/).

Also, see [this explaination](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380736/can-the-word-ignorant-be-used-as-a-noun).