# Use of an adverb or an adjective as a subject

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I read the chain on whether "the information below" or "the below information" is correct usage- consensus was that both are, although I distinctly prefer the former.  I have noticed a really irritating relatd trend, mostly in email, where the sender references simply "the below" without including an object.  I work a lot with Indian colleagues, and it is rife in their communications, but I have also seen it increasingly in US based communications, including in a delivery notice email from FedEx ("To help ensure successful delivery of your shipment, please review the below.").  Before I ban my team from using it ever again, I just want to be sure that it is grammatically incorrect.  I think it's a great example of how electronic communications are changing our language, beyond texting lingo. I am not sure pointing out that it is incorrect will change anything, but it just drives me crazy everytime I see it.

Comment: The poor are with us always. The below will depend on context. I'd say that use of 'the below' and certainly 'the above' are accepted as being fully grammatical now. It's hard to argue the opposite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["the above" is correct, "the below" is not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172709/the-above-is-correct-the-below-is-not). For an overview of the grammar involved, fused modifier-head constructions, see Araucaria's post  at [on reading the sacred](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389481/on-reading-the-sacred/389485#389485).

Comment: What’s wrong with *the below* when we say *the above*?

Comment: Makes sense.  Guess it's on me to accept it now.  Thank you!